# Execute function based on percentage given

Tags: javascript, algorithm, percentage

So I have two functions

```
   function toWin(){
      console.log('win')
   }

   function toLose(){
      console.log('lose')
   }
```

how do I get each functions to be executed based on the percentage given?
Say in 100 tries, `toWin()` should be executed 90 times, and randomly.

I'd like to change the `win_percentage` to any number any time.

```
   var win_percentage = 90; // 90 percent

   function generateResultRandomly(){
      //code to execute either function should be here.
   }
```

If there's any other way I can get this without my methods, it'll be appreciated, or you could help in writing the algorithm and I code it out.

Comment: Are you familiar with `Math.random()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Yes I am, But I want each functions be executed based on the number of tries assigned

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var win_percentage = 90; // 90 percent

function generateResultRandomly(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101); // returns a random integer from 0 to 100
  if (random <= win_percentage) {
      toWin();
  } else {
      toLose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I used for loop to try the code and checked the total wins and lose, at the end the win percentage is always higher (around 88 - 95), but I would love to make it absolutely precise, I mean make it absolutely 90 wins from 100 tries.

Comment: If you increase the for loop, i think the win percent will approximate to 90

Comment: Thanks, i think this video will be good for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETphJASzYes&feature=share